# How to make scatter plot with 2 arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have to arrays of integers:
pts_array and opp_pts_array

I wanted to create a dataFrame and then plot it:

```
dfscatter = pd.DataFrame(np.array([pts_array, opp_pts_array]), columns=['points', 'opponent points'])
dfscatter.plot.scatter(x='points', y='opponent points')
```

However, it is not working.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: *it is not working*: what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pts_array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
opp_pts_array = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

d = {'points':pts_array,'opponent_points':opp_pts_array}
dfscatter = pd.DataFrame(d)

dfscatter.plot.scatter(x='points', y='opponent_points')
```

There you go.